# numpy - Sample repeatedly from matrix using np.random.choice

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy, numerical-methods

I have a 2D array, where each row is a direction:

```
directions = np.array([[ 1, 0],
                       [-1, 0],
                       [ 0, 1],
                       [ 0,-1]])
```

I want to sample several rows from this, and then do a `cumsum` (to simulate a random walk). The best approach would be to use `np.random.choice`. For instance, to sample 10 steps, do this:

```
np.random.choice(directions, size=(10,1))
# returns 2D array of shape (10,2), where each row is
# randomly sampled from the previous one
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional
```

Now, I realize I have a 2D array, but shouldn't it act like a 1D-array of 1D arrays in this context? Isn't this how the broadcasting rules work?

So, my questions is how do I make this 2D array act as a 1D array of 1D arrays (i.e., the 2 element columns).

Comment: Why do you need `np.r_` in the first bit of code? It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: This has nothing to do with broadcasting. The function will only accept scalars or 1D integers see [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1087).

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, the `np.r_` were a relic from a previous version of the code, in which I was trying working with a Python list of numpy arrays..

Comment: @kain88. Or [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably be to use indexing. The first argument to `choice` is described as follows:

> If an ndarray, a random sample is generated from its elements. If an int, the random sample is generated as if a was np.arange(n)

You can do this:

```
directions = np.array([[ 1, 0],
                       [-1, 0],
                       [ 0, 1],
                       [ 0,-1]])
sampleInd = np.random.choice(directions.shape[0], size=(10,))
sample = directions[sampleInd]
```

Note that if you want the result to be a 2D array, specify the choice output as a 1D `(10,)` vector rather than `(10, 1)`, which is 2D.

Now the final destination of your random walk is

```
destination = np.sum(sample, axis = 0)
```

The argument `axis = 0` is necessary because otherwise `sum` will add up all the elements in the 2D `sample` array rather than adding each column separately.

Comment: the last line is directions[sampleInd]?

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Fixed.

Comment: sure, I was preparing a very similar answer too.

Comment: @ericmjl I'm just starting with numpy coming from matlab and vanilla python, so all I do is read the docs these days :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `numpy.random.choice` is to use `random.choice` in the standard library.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: directions = np.array([[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]])

In [3]: directions
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1,  0],
       [-1,  0],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 0, -1]])

In [4]: from numpy.random import choice

In [5]: choice(directions)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-dd768952d6d1> in <module>()
----> 1 choice(directions)

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:10365)()

ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional

In [6]: import random

In [7]: random.choice(directions)
Out[7]: array([ 0, -1])

In [8]: choices = []

In [9]: for i in range(10):
   ...:     choices.append(random.choice(directions))
   ...:     

In [10]: choices
Out[10]: 
[array([1, 0]),
 array([ 0, -1]),
 array([ 0, -1]),
 array([-1,  0]),
 array([1, 0]),
 array([ 0, -1]),
 array([ 0, -1]),
 array([ 0, -1]),
 array([-1,  0]),
 array([1, 0])]

In [11]:
```

Comment: This does something different from what is being asked. The OP wants a sequence of random samples from the input, not a single sample.

Comment: This is potentially very slow. I wouldn't use to generate random walks. The problem is that you have to make a lot of calls to the rng in python itself, which is slow in my experience. Using numpy and obtaining the complete set of random choices at once is better here.

Comment: Also, how do you plan to sum the list of arrays along the 0-th dimension? The ultimate goal is to find where the random walk ends up.

Comment: Another for loop would be the way to go. I would assume you would know how to do this, of course, @Mad Physicist. Naturally, though, I recognize that this is the slower option compared to using `numpy`. I myself put this answer out there to generate this discussion.